# Why IndexedDB store much larger size then my actual data

Tags: reactjs, indexeddb, dexie

I have *7.1MB* JSON data containing 30 base64 string.
e.g. `{'records: ["string_1", "string_2", ...]}`

If I save each record in a separate entry. IndexedDB might produce *56MB* of data. i.e.

```
key | value
--- | --------
0   | string_1
1   | string_2
...
```

If all data save in a single entry as `File` or `JSON String`, IndexedDB needs exactly *7.1MB* only. i.e.

```
key | value
--- | --------
0   | {'records: ["string_1", "string_2", ...]}
```

Why would this happen?